# Partitioning a table refenceing other

Tags: oracle, constraints, partition

I have a target table `T1` which doesn't have a Date field. The current size is increasing rapidly. Hence I need to add a Date field and also perform table partitioning on this target table.

```
T1 has PRIMARY KEY (DOCID, LABID)
 and has CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (DOCID) REFERENCES T2
```

Table `T2` is also complex table and has many rules in it.

```
T2 has PRIMARY KEY (DOCID)
```

My question is, as I need to partition T1. Is it possible NOT TO perform any step for T2 before T1 is partition? DBA told me that I need to partition T2 first before I touch T1??

Comment: The question is if a Partitioned table can have a FK constraint referencing a non partitioned table?

Comment: Just to be clear, the referenced table T2 doesn't have the date that you plan to partition T1 on - so you aren't talking about [reference partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#CACIHDII)? So what would you partition T1 on? Or, what did your DBA recommend, and did they explain why?

Comment: @RicardoArnold You are correct.
.

Comment: @AlexPoole You are correct too. The referenced table T2 has a date on which I guess T1 will be partitioned on.

Comment: So you're adding another FK on T2 that references the date on T1? Did you look at the doc I linked to before? Partitioning T1 would reduce duplicated data and maintenance. You don't have to do that but you might as well. Do you have a reason to go against your DBA's advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to partition T2 before partitioning T1. Foreign key constraints do not care in the slightest bit about partitioning.

Best of luck.

Comment: Can you please share any related link which can put some light on my scenario.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have – as proposed by others - two options. The first one is to add a redundant column `DATE` to the table T1 (child) and introduce the range partitioning on this column.

The second option is to use reference partitioning. Below is the simplified DDL for those options.

**Range partitioning on child**

```
create table T2_P2 /* parent */
(docid number not null,
 trans_date date not null,
 pad varchar2(100),
 CONSTRAINT t2_p2_pk PRIMARY KEY(docid)
 );

create table T1_P2 /* child */
(docid number not null,
 labid number not null,
 trans_date date not null,  /** redundant column **/
 pad varchar2(100),
 CONSTRAINT t1_p2_pk PRIMARY KEY(docid, labid),
 CONSTRAINT t1_p2_fk
 FOREIGN KEY(docid) REFERENCES T2_P2(docid) 
 )
   PARTITION BY RANGE(trans_date)
    ( PARTITION Q1_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')) 
    );
```

**Reference partition**

```
create table T2_RP /* parent */
(docid number not null,
 trans_date date not null,
 pad varchar2(100),
 CONSTRAINT t2_rp_pk PRIMARY KEY(docid)
 )
   PARTITION BY RANGE(trans_date)
    ( PARTITION Q1_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')) 
    );

create table T1_RP /* child */
(docid number not null,
 labid number not null,
 pad varchar2(100),
 CONSTRAINT t1_rp_pk PRIMARY KEY(docid, labid),
 CONSTRAINT t1_rp_fk
 FOREIGN KEY(docid) REFERENCES T2_RP(docid) 
 )
 PARTITION BY REFERENCE(t1_rp_fk);
```

Your question is basically if the first option is possible, so the **answer is YES**.

To decide if the first option is *preferable* I’d suggest checking three criteria:

**Migration**

The first option requires a new DATE column in the child table that must be initialized during the migration (and of course correct maintained by the application).

**Lifecycle**

It could be that the lifecycle of both tables is the same (e.g. both parent and child records are kept for 7 year). In this case is preferable if both tables are partitioned (on the same key).

**Access**

For queries such as below you will profit from the reference partitioning (both tables are pruned - i.e. only the partitions with the accessed date are queried).

```
select * from T2_RP T2 join T1_RP T1 on t2.docid = t1.docid
where t2.trans_date = to_date('01012016','ddmmyyyy');
```

In the first option you will (probalbly) end with FTS on T2 and to get pruning on T1 you need to add predicate `T2.trans_date = t1.trans_date`

Having said that, I do not claim that the reference partition is superior. But I think it's worth to examine both options in your context and see which one is better.